# How to call smart contract methods without abi?

Tags: web3.py, python, abi

I need to call a smart contract from python, but it is not verified. Since this is not my contract, I cannot verify it. How to call the smart contract methods through python in this case?
Smart contract: https://explorer.dogechain.dog/address/0x4aE2bD0666c76C7f39311b9B3e39b53C8D7C43Ea/contracts#address-tabs

Comment: You'll need the contract's ABI.

Answer (score 0):

If you can work out what is being sent you can recraft it and send the raw data with a normal transaction, just steal the function sig and pad your values correctly.

Example [raw transfer](https://github.com/0xMaka/w3py/blob/main/raw_transfer.py):
[image: raw transfer]

In your case you can see they have exactInputSingle(), so you can guess that and other similar Uniswap functions are also in the multicalls, search signatures in the [4byte directory](https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0xbc651188) and break the calls down:
[image: searching function sig]

You could also write your own abi for that function or take from a contract with the same function and arguments. Look up sig/arguments on 4byte directory.

Have done this with an unverified farming contract that was just passing pid, amount and address to withdraw.

Something like:
[image: a minimal abi]